# Compare two dictionnaries in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have two dictionaries from an ansible task:

```yaml
users_space:
  peter: 5
  jhon: 3

groups_space:
  peter: '4'
  jhon: '3'
```

I would like to compare the values for those 2 dictionaries and fail when values are different.

I want my task to fail for example when a value for the same key in the second dictionaries is not equal.

Keys are always the same but unordered.

Example:
fail when peter value is not the same in the two dictionaries

**NOTE that the values from the `groups_space` dictionary are not integers and need to be converted before comparison**

I'd like to have something like:

```yaml
- fail:
    msg: "please check the value from *dictionary_name*".
  when: value is different for the same key in the two dictionaries"
```

I tried this but it did not give the expected result.

```yaml
- fail:
    msg: "{{ item }} is {{ (users_space[item] == groups_space[item]) }}"
  loop: "{{ groups_space.keys()|sort }}"
  when: qsi_disk_space.key != quota_qsi.key
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a dict with values converted to int:

```yaml
groups_keys: "{{ groups_space.keys() }}"
groups_values: "{{ groups_space.values() | map('int') }}"
fixed_groups_space: "{{ dict(groups_keys | zip(groups_values)) }}"
```

This gives:

```json
{
    "fixed_groups_space": {
        "john": 3,
        "peter": 4
    }
}
```

From there, the comparison is trivial:

```yaml
is_equal_dict: "{{ users_space == fixed_groups_space }}"
```

Here is a complete playbook to test it with passing and failing cases:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    users_space:
      peter: 5
      john: 3

    yes_users_space: 
      john: 3
      peter: 4

    groups_space:
      peter: '4'
      john: '3'

    groups_keys: "{{ groups_space.keys() }}"
    groups_values: "{{ groups_space.values() | map('int') }}"
    fixed_groups_space: "{{ dict(groups_keys | zip(groups_values)) }}"

  tasks:
    - name: That one is expected to succeed
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: yes_users_space == fixed_groups_space

    - name: This one is expected to fail
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: users_space == fixed_groups_space
```

Running it gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [That one is expected to succeed] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

TASK [This one is expected to fail] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "users_space == fixed_groups_space",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "Assertion failed"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer but the playbook does not like the filter: | map('int')

I have the following error
TASK [sftp : debug] ************************************************************
ok: [server] => 
  fixed_groups_space:
    john: <
    peter: g

When I take out the map filter map('int') I have no error but still with the string but not integer value

Comment: Something else I can use instead of map('int') to convert it to integer ?

Comment: No, you can figure out why "it isn't working" when it should and provide a [mre] if you are still stuck. Because as demonstrated above, it "works". A common cause of filters and examples not working as expected is using an outdated and unsupported ansible version. Please make sure you installed at least ansible-core 2.12. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#ansible-core-support-matrix

Answer (score 1):

This builds upon the answer from @Zeitounator, while also considering your desire to alter the original groups_space dictionary.  It is possible to recreate the groups_space dictonary.

```yaml
#test_playbook.yaml
---
# YAML documents begin with the document separator ---

-
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  # Vars: variables that will apply to the play, on all target systems
  vars:
    users_space:
      peter: 5
      jhon: 3
        
    groups_space:
      peter: '5'
      jhon: '3'

  # Tasks: the list of tasks that will be executed within the play, this section
  #       can also be used for pre and post tasks
  tasks:
    - name: Fix groups_space
      set_fact:
        groups_space: "{{ groups_space | combine(fixed_item, recursive=true) }}"
      vars:
        fixed_item: "{ '{{ item.key }}': {{ item.value |int }} }"
      with_dict: "{{ groups_space }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ groups_space }}"
        
    - name: Test equality
      assert:
        that:
          - groups_space == users_space     
...
```

Note that this passes, which was your original issue with value mismatching.  You can change a value in either array to test whether the assertion fails when values don't match.

```
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Fix groups_space] *****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': u'5', 'key': u'peter'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': u'3', 'key': u'jhon'})

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "jhon": 3, 
        "peter": 5
    }
}

TASK [Test equality] ********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score -1):

I Have worked like this:

```yaml
- name: Create new dictionary 
  set_fact:
    fixed_space: "{{ space_int }}"
  vars:
    dict_space: "{{ groups_space|dict2items|json_query(space_keys)|items2dict  }}"
    space_keys: "{{ '[].{key: key, value: value}' }}"
    space_int: "{{ dict(dict_space.keys()|
                     zip(dict_space.values()|
                         map('int'))) }}"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).